# Unit testing spring boot controller with Mockito

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I have the following controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("cats")
public class CatController {
    private IDatabaseCatDao databaseCatService;
    private DataValidator catDataValidator;

    public CatController(IDatabaseCatDao databaseCatService, DataValidator catDataValidator) {
        this.databaseCatService = databaseCatService;
        this.catDataValidator = catDataValidator;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity addCat(@RequestBody Cat cat) {
        catDataValidator.validateCatAdding(cat, cats);
        databaseCatService.addCat(cat);
        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().buildAndExpand(cat.getName()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();
    }
}
```

*catDataValidator* - check if data is correct
*databaseCatService* - insert in database + caching locally

I need to test It using ***jUnit*** and ***Mockito***.

My test class is following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = CatController.class, secure = false)
public class CatControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private IDatabaseCatDao databaseCatService;

    private String catExampleJson = "..some json file..";

   public void addCat() throws Exception {
        Mockito.doNothing().when(databaseCatService).addCat(Mockito.any(Cat.class));
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post("/cats")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(catExampleJson)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

*Mockito.doNothing()* because service addCat() is void method.
*Validation* I should better test separetely
*Cats map* I don't use here

java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

```
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:137)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I have the following ***dependencies for the testing***:

spring-boot-starter-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate your test method with `@Test` for the SpringRunner to be able to find it.  i.e.:

```
@Test
public void addCat() throws Exception {
```

Comment: oh my god..it's imbossible, ty

Comment: Could you tell me please about Mockito.doNothing(), when I try to invoke void method(), when I have some exception inside this method It wouldn't work, right?

Comment: `Mockito.doNothing()` is most useful when you use a `Spy` instead of a `Mock`, since you can prevent an unwanted method from being executed on a real object.

Comment: You could, but not with a `Mock`.  You'd have to use a `Spy`.  There's a `@SpyBean` annotation for that.  But it's *highly* discouraged to use spies unless you have no other choice.  The better approach is to create a new test class to specifically test whatever class that you're interested in.